# How can I protect myself against this hack in Neotokyo?

Tags: mods, neotokyo

While playing Neotokyo (Halflife 2 full conversion or CS variant, depending on whom you ask), someone trolled all or most players in one of the following ways:

- change keybindings so that pressing w would spam a textmessage ("I was hacked by team Gamerfood" or advertisment to their site
- change mouse senstivity, making playing practically impossible
- changing players names to their URL (that I won't advertise here)

All of it easily reverted by resetting the config to default. But it seriously got on my nerves, and I guess on other peoples nerves too. How do I protect myself from this kind of hack? When the only one able to do something is the one running the server, I'd still like an answer that I can point to.

I play the game via steam.

Comment: Is there a tag for "asshole players" or something like that? Is there one for hacking other players like that? Please improve the tagging of this question!

Comment: I was always interested in a "gamer-ethics" kind of tag but I don't think it would get much traction.

Comment: @Flaunting Please do not add needless tags to questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'll gladly accept an authoritative answer from someone who knows steam and the issue at hand better. Here's what I gathered from [a thread on the steam forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/244630/discussions/0/43099722341653744/):
Team Gamerfood runs servers under the same names as popular servers, and uses the admin functions to change players cfg files in the manner described above. To protect yourself, play on a different server.

While it may sound like a neat idea to advertise a website offering cheats and the like via "hacking" other players, the first impression I gathered was "They do this, I bet their site is ful of malware."

Again, I don't know the first thing about running CS servers and so I don't know if this is plausible. But I wanted the little I know to be available to others who had for the same problem.

Comment: One easy way to tell one of there servers then is to look at the player names in the game before joining